# angular 5 ngModelOptions updateOn multipile events

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

I want my input model updated with more than one event:
for now, I have seen that angular 5 support one event for example - [ngModelOptions]={updateOn:'blur'}.

Can I have more than one for example: [ngModelOptions]={updateOn:'blur submit'}

I think this is supported in angular 1.

**soultion**

I want to update the modal on two events - blur and submit:

1. I use [ngModelOptions]={updateOn:'blur'} - this will update the modal on blur.
2. Once the user will press enter - I will blur from the input. I did this with a directive on the form tag:

10x to Itay b.m for the directive!!

```
@Directive({

    selector: '[enterEvent]',   

    host: { '(keypress)': 'onkeydown($event)'}

})

export class EnterEventDirective {

    constructor() {      

    }  

    onkeydown(event) {     

        if (event.key == "Enter") {           

            event.target.blur();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20371

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use the submit button like this.

```
<button type="submit" (click)="submitbtn.focus();submit();" #submitbtn>Submit</button>
```

So when the user presses the enter key it will fire blur event because focus shift to the submit button. If the submit button is disabled then this will not work.

Sample Code:

```
    <form #myForm="ngForm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
         #spy>
        <br>TODO: remove this: {{spy.className}}
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required [(ngModel)]="model.name1" name="name1" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
         #spy1>
        <br>TODO: remove this: {{spy1.className}}
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="submitbtn.focus();submit();" #submitbtn>Submit</button>
        <br> {{output}}
    </form>
```

Angular class:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  model={
    name:"",
    name1:""
  }
  output="";

  submit(){
    this.output=JSON.stringify(this.model);
  }
}
```